# Sed:Replace a series of dots with one underscore

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, sed

I want to do some simple string replace in Bash with sed. I am Ubuntu 10.10.

Just see the following code, it is self-explanatory:

```
name="A%20Google.."
echo $name|sed 's/\%20/_/'|sed 's/\.+/_/'
```

I want to get `A_Google_` but I get `A_Google..`

The `sed 's/\.+/_/'` part is obviously wrong.

BTW, `sed 's/\%20/_/'` and `sed 's/%20/_/'` both work. Which is better?

Comment: Hunch: try `'s/\.\.*/_/'`. Your sed may not be handling the `+` correctly.

Comment: @Beta: Hi I would like to know why `sed 's/\.*/_/'` wont work. Thanks.

Comment: Because `\.*` will match any number of dots, including zero, such as the no dots at the beginning of "A_Google..".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sed` speaks POSIX basic regular expressions, which don't include `+` as a metacharacter.  Portably, rewrite to use `*`:

```
sed 's/\.\.*/_/'
```

or if all you will ever care about is Linux, you can use various GNU-isms:

```
sed -r 's/\.\.*/_/'    # turn on POSIX EREs (use -E instead of -r on OS X)
sed 's/\.\+/_/'        # GNU regexes invert behavior when backslash added/removed
```

That last example answers your other question:  a character which is literal when used as is may take on a special meaning when backslashed, and even though *at the moment* `%` doesn't have a special meaning when backslashed, future-proofing means not assuming that `\%` is safe.

Additional note:  you don't need two separate `sed` commands in the pipeline there.

```
echo $name | sed -e 's/\%20/_/' -e 's/\.+/_/'
```

(Also, do you only need to do that once per line, or for all occurrences?  You may want the `/g` modifier.)

Comment: I dont quite understand your `\%` part. You mean `\%` has no special meaning but this may change in the future? So `%` is a better solution. I dont know when I should add the backslash and when not.

Comment: You have to know what regex language is in use, and the `%` vs. `\%` thing is complicated by the GNU interpretation of POSIX where an ERE metacharacter that isn't present in BREs can be backslashed to get the ERE meaning (so `\+` means a literal `+` in most versions of `sed`, but in GNU `sed` it means one or more of what precedes it). Unfortunately, the regex landscape is a nightmare with hidden land mines, and will remain so for the foreseeable future; you have no choice but to know exactly what regex engine a program uses and what the quirks of that engine are.

Answer (score 2):

The `sed` command doesn't understand `+` so you'll have to expand it by hand:

```
sed 's/\.\.*/_/'
```

Or tell `sed` that you want to use extended regexes:

```
sed -r 's/\.+/_/' # GNU
sed -E 's/\.+/_/' # OSX
```

Which switch, `-r` or `-E`, depends on your `sed` and it might not even support extended regexes so the portable solution is to use `\.\.*` in place of `\.+`. But, since you're on Linux, you should have GNU `sed` so `sed -r` should do the trick.